# What type of TextBox Editor using in stackoverflow for asking questions and post the answers

Tags: text-editor

What type of TextBox Editor using in stackoverflow for asking questions and post the answers.

I am not sure but It sounds like some kind of jQuery plugin

Can any one please help us to figure this out ?

Kind Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533586/what-wysiwyg-editor-does-stackoverflow-use-closed

Answer (score 0):

It is a modified version of WMD.